# Something wrong with galton box project results in java

Tags: java

> I've written this piece of code to simulate a galton box for a school project:

'''
public class GaltonBoxProject {

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    //This will keep track of the final positions and will sort them

    int[] finalColumns = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    //will track current pos of the ball

    //8 tiers

    //start from middle of the box

    int randChance;

    for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {

        int currentPos = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            //resets the number

            randChance = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;

            //if less than 50 go to the left

            //if 0 --> +

            //if 8 --> -

            if(currentPos == 0 && randChance > 50) {

                currentPos++;

            }

            else if (currentPos == 7 && randChance <= 50) {

                currentPos--;

            }

            else if(currentPos != 7 && currentPos != 0 && randChance > 50){

                currentPos++;

            }

            else if(currentPos != 7 && currentPos != 0 && randChance < 50){

                currentPos--;

            }

            //If you want to know why I got these results

            //I genuinely can't find the reason why this pattern happens

            //System.out.print(" RAND: " + randChance);

            //System.out.println(" POS: " + currentPos);

        }

        //Also debugging

        //System.out.println(a + " CURRENT POS: " + currentPos);

        //This will sort the numbers

        for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++){

            if(k == currentPos){

                finalColumns[k]++;

            }

        }

    }

    //for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {

    //    System.out.println("KEY: " + finalColumns[i]);

    }

    for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++){

        System.out.print(k + ": ");

        for(int j = 0; j < finalColumns[k]; j++){

            System.out.print("*");

        }

        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

'''

> I get this result:

> 0: ********

> 1: ********

> 2: **********************

> 3: ***

> 4: ******************************

> 5: *****

> 6: *****************

> I should be getting a bell curve and I don't know why the code is doing this

Comment: Your code is rather long. Is the visualization at the end necessary? If not, just print the numbers.

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting so that people can read your Question without getting a headache?  For a start, there shouldn't be a blank line between each line of code.